# Add New users to a particular chatter group

Tags: trigger

I want to add the newly created users to be added to a chatter group based on the value on the department description( test field), and the Department id (number field)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Fetch Group
CollaborationGroup group = [SELECT id FROM CollaborationGroup WHERE Name=:groupName LIMIT 1];
// Fetch User to be added in group
User[] userList = [SELECT id FROM USER WHERE ... some filter you want];
// List to store new members
List<CollaborationGroupMember> CollGroupMembers = new List<CollaborationGroupMember>();
for (User userList: users) 
{
        // Create new member
        CollaborationGroupMember member = new CollaborationGroupMember();
        // Add userId
        member.MemberId = userList.Id ;
        // Assign group id to new member
        member.CollaborationGroupId = group.Id ;
        groupMembers.add(member);
}

insert CollGroupMembers;
```

Comment: I will certainly try this, appreciate for your quick responses.